# AssemblyBuilder reference assembly

Tags: .net, reflection, reflection.emit

I am creating a new Assembly using System.Reflection.Emit.
I want the new assembly to reference another assembly. There is a method `GetReferencedAssemblies()` that gets all the referenced assemblies, but there is no method to reference a new one. How can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An old question i know, but assuming someone else like me stumbles upon it...

The answer I eventually found is that you don't need to add a reference when creating a new assembly.   References related to types used in the code you Emit are automatically "added".

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're right, that was what I found out after I asked this question too.